# getting the last insert_id mysqli active record Design pattern php

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone help me get the last Inserted id from an active record design patten, i tried several ways but get 0.

this is the Code i try at the last.

```
$dbo = database::getInstance();
$dbo->connect('userwish');

$userInfo = new userInfo();
$data1 = array("gender" =>$_POST['gender'],"accompanied"=>$_POST['accompanied']);
$userInfo->bind($data1);
$userInfo->id = $id;
$userInfo->store();
$lastId = $userInfo->id;
var_dump($lastId);
```

Comment: 1) you're not defining $id (at least within this snippet).
2) Does var_dump($userInfo->id); change before and after calling store(); 3) From memory you shouldn't need to explicitly store data with active records, rather it should be 'active' as you bind/update fields.

Comment: Can you be specific about you opinion, because i can only get last  inserted id after insert is triggered, and my store() is function to insert if called. but may be you may be right but be specific or  give me an example of what you mean

Comment: You're assigning an $id, then saving it and... expecting it to change?  Why store it in the first instance - it'll be `null` by default within your `userInfo()` class and the resulting object.  So the question is - what are you expecting $lastId to be and what are you getting instead?

Comment: I am getting Input values from a dynamic UI, those values are been saftly inserted in my database, but i then plan an ER model for the Tables so i Need this last inserted id to the foreign key. i actually have been implementing procedural and i have been getting  the last inserted id's

Comment: Crux of this is that `->store()` isn't setting the `$id` attrib; so the code shown only higlights which method is at fault - not the code itself.